# If user has no profile show 404

Tags: php, cakephp

On my app a user may or may not have a profile. An example would be:

```
Array
(
    [User] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [username] => noprofile
            [password] => 3b8cdb0c849f00f3634d9b29def1dac4e9235795
            [email] => noprofile@noprofile.com
            [status] => 0
            [code] => 114a10ebb6ffe364805aa70cd44bee7c
        )

    [Profile] => Array
        (
            [id] => 
            [firstname] => 
            [lastname] => 
            [gender] => 
            [dob] => 
            [user_id] => 
        )

)
```

Here the user noprofile has no matching content in the profiles table.

How do I show a 404 for when this happens? I've tried:

```
public function view ( $username )
{
    $this->Profile->User->recursive = 2;

    $profile = $this->Profile->User->find('first', array( 
                'conditions' => array('User.username' => $username) 
            ));

    if (empty($profile))
    {
        echo 'echo1';
        throw new NotFoundException('No profile');
    }
    else {
        echo 'echo2';
    }

    $this->set(compact('profile'));
}
```

But it doesn't show the 404! I'm using CakePHP 2.0.

It's because it finds the user so therefore profile is not empty! How do I check for the profile being empty then?

Comment: Check the value of $profile and also check that you are indeed entering the if statement and executing the cakeError.

Comment: How do I check that as I don't have an IDE to check if get there

Comment: You don't need an IDE. print/echo the $profile variable before the if statement and then print/echo a string something like "Hey I am in the IF statement" inside your if statement.

Comment: Okies seems that CakePHP does not see the profile as empty because it's finding the user. See OP and I get the second echo even if no profile exists. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (empty($profile['Profile']['id'])) {
    throw new NotFoundException();
}
```

I expect there are better ways to do it but that's a quick fix. `$profile`, as you said, will not be empty as the `user` is found.

Answer (score 2):

cakephp 2.0 has changed the way to display errors. Now you have to [throw an exception](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html#built-in-exceptions-for-cakephp). In your case, instead of :

```
$this->cakeError('error404');
```

you have to do:

```
throw new NotFoundException();
```

**Edited:**
On the other hand, you migth want to do a JOIN in your find query (and recursive -1), to foce the query to retreive the user's info ONLY if he has a profile.

Hope this helps

Comment: I still get access to the page (even in production mode)

Comment: have you tried using a join in the find query?.. try debugging your code. `pr($profile)` besides, `empty($profile)` will always return false, because the profile is probably something like `array("name=>'','lastname'=>'',...)`